# How to importe a module in a Vue Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules

I've created a `script.js` file, which is used to create a custom mouse trail. In normal HTML projects, I would use it by typing this at the end of the  tag.

```
<script src="./mouseTrail.js" type="module"></script>
```

How can I achieve the same result in a Vue Project without getting the error?

```
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use the external type 'module' within a script
```

Below is the `mouseTrail.js` file. Its not the complete file but included the important code.

```js
import {
  Polyline,
  Renderer,
  Transform,
  Geometry,
  Program,
  Mesh,
  Vec3,
  Vec2,
  Color
} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ogl@0.0.25/dist/ogl.mjs';

const vertex = `
  attribute vec3 position;
  attribute vec3 next;
  attribute vec3 prev;
  attribute vec2 uv;
  attribute float side;

  uniform vec2 uResolution;
  uniform float uDPR;
  uniform float uThickness;

  vec4 getPosition() {
      vec2 aspect = vec2(uResolution.x / uResolution.y, 1);
      vec2 nextScreen = next.xy * aspect;
      vec2 prevScreen = prev.xy * aspect;

      vec2 tangent = normalize(nextScreen - prevScreen);
      vec2 normal = vec2(-tangent.y, tangent.x);
      normal /= aspect;
      normal *= 1.0 - pow(abs(uv.y - 0.5) * 1.9, 2.0);

      float pixelWidth = 1.0 / (uResolution.y / uDPR);
      normal *= pixelWidth * uThickness;


      float dist = length(nextScreen - prevScreen);
      normal *= smoothstep(0.0, 0.02, dist);

      vec4 current = vec4(position, 1);
      current.xy -= normal * side;
      return current;
  }

  void main() {
      gl_Position = getPosition();
  }
`
```

Comment: How did you create the project? Are you importing anything in `mouseTrail.js`?

Comment: created the project using Vue CLI and the mouseTrail file is importing some OGL modules via CDN    'import {Polyline,renderer,Vec3,Vec2} from  'cdn link '  '

Comment: Can you post the `mouseTrail.js` content?

Comment: Of course      @stellr42

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the [ogl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ogl) module via npm instead of fetching the module via a http link:

```
npm install --save ogl
```

```
import { ... } from 'ogl';
```